# Regex match if first instance of string is followed by string -- force lazy

Tags: regex, tasker

I am trying to return a match only if the first instance of a string is followed by another string. However they may appear later on, but I don't want a match then.

```
Thing #1
.........
hidden=true
.........
Thing #2
.........
hidden=false
.........
```

Right now I am using `Thing #1[\S\s]*?hidden=false` but obviously that will return a match for the above example when I don't want it to. Only if the first hidden= is followed by false. I know how it could be done with a capture group but that would greatly complicate things for me, I am using Tasker on Android and capture groups are a huge ordeal and slow. How can I do this?

Comment: What about just finding the first occurrence of "hidden=" and checking if the string following it is true or false.  Regex seems overkill.

Comment: @Kelvin it might not be the first occurrence. I care about the first occurrence *after* "Thing #1". Later these will be mixed around and I will be interested in other ones as well.

Comment: Then find the index of "Thing #1", then find the first occurrence of "hidden=" starting after the index of "Thing #1".

Comment: @Kelvin Given that I am using Tasker, that is already more complicated than just using a capture group which is slow and complicated.

Comment: Hmm if capturing group is slow then lookaheads will be even more worrisome :)

Comment: @anubhava It's not the regex that is slow, it is tasker. The regex is run in Java but then anything I do in tasker is super high level laggy slow. You can actually watch it as it does simple variable assigning and conditionals. That's why I want it figured out in the regex and not have to manipulate it further than true/false with tasker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. You just need to prevent another `Thing #1` from being between the matched thing and the next marker.

Use a negative look ahead:

```
Thing #1((?!Thing #1)[\S\s])*?hidden=false
```

Comment: Ah, ok I think you mean `Thing #1((?!hidden)[\S\s])*?hidden=false` to prevent any hiddens to happen before the first one. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This negative regex will search for first `Thing #<number>` instance in the text if it is followed by `hidden=false`:

```
^.*?Thing #\d+(?:(?!hidden=(?:true|false))[\S\s])*?hidden=false
```

There won't be any match if `hidden=true` is found first.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8ADCQ/3)